# Boost's stacktrace library doesn't work with C++ CLI

Tags: boost, c++-cli, boost-stacktrace

I have been using the Boost stacktrace library to print out a stacktrace of my program.

[Boost 1.78.0](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/stacktrace.html)

When compiling with pure C++ it compiles and my program prints the stacktrace nicely.
However when compiling with C++ /CLI, my program doesn't print the stacktrace.

Here is my reproducable example :

```
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::stringstream stack;
    stack << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
    std::string stacktrace = stack.str();      // The string "stacktrace" is empty when running with C++ CLI
    std::cout << stacktrace;
}
```

Compiling this with C++ /CLI doesn't print the stacktrace to stdout, whereas compiling with pure C++ does print it to stdout.

Another thing is that when I use `boost/stacktrace/stacktrace.hpp` instead of `boost/stacktrace.hpp` my program fails to print the stacktrace even in pure C++.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any references to this issue on stack overflow.

I am on Windows, and I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

I am using Boost version Version: 1.78.0.

I installed boost with vcpkg.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Boost Stacktrace claims CLR support.

I'd expect some output, but not particularly useful output.

Of course, in CLR mode, you can use .NET stacktraces: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=net-6.0

> Another thing is that when I use boost/stacktrace/stacktrace.hpp instead of boost/stacktrace.hpp my program fails to print the stacktrace even in pure C++.

That's probably because that's not correct usage. There's many nuts and bolts to configuring the library correctly, see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html. One of the possible configurations leads to no-op implementation.

Comment: Hmm what about System::Environment::StackTrace

Comment: Dunno. That mostly looks older https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.stacktrace?view=net-6.0#applies-to vs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=net-6.0#applies-to. Also it just returns the string. As the docs say [For a hierarchical view of the stack trace information by class, use the StackTrace class.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.stacktrace?view=net-6.0#:~:text=For%20a%20hierarchical%20view%20of%20the%20stack%20trace%20information%20by%20class%2C%20use%20the%20StackTrace%20class)